# Getting an integer from the console

Tags: haskell, input

Is there a way to read an integer from the console in Haskell? I'm asking for something pretty much like C++'s cin or Java's Scanner.nextInt().

And by that I mean that given this input:

```
1 2 3
2 3
4 25 12 7
1
```

I should be able to read them all, not at the same time (maybe reading 4 of them, doing some calculations and then read the rest) ignoring the fact that they are in separate lines.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is probably

```
getAll :: Read a => IO [a] 
getAll = fmap (fmap read . words) getContents

getInts :: IO [Int]
getInts = getAll
```

which will read all input into a single list.

Comment: This does not satisfy the criteria "not at the same time".  I would recommend to the OP to design in a way that works with this approach, as it will be more in Haskell's spirit.  At the same time, this does not answer the question posed.

Comment: @luqui: "I should be able to read them all": check, by `getContents`. "ignoring the fact that they are in separate lines": check (`words`). "not at the same time": still check, since `getContents` is lazy and neither `map`, `words` nor the `fmap` of `[]` or `IO` is strict. This answer won't work when there is some other content than integers on stdin, and lazy IO isn't that great, but as far as I can see it fulfils the requirements.

Comment: It indeed fulfills the requirements I posted (I've just tested it) except the one where I said I should be able to read some integers, do some calculations and then read some more integers, but I can live with that as I have them all stored after all.

Also, is there a way to modify this so I can tell it the number of Ints I want to read from the input stream?

Comment: @Setzer22: `getInts` is a lazily generated list of integers. You can read the first five (`take 5`), and later get the rest `drop 5`. You can also split the list using [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt).

Comment: Well, I didn't actually mean that. I meant actually choosing to get 5 integers from stdin, and leave the rest in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

*When in doubt, use Parsec!* (not always, and not really, but who cares)

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Numbers

value = do 
    spaces
    num <- parseFloat
    return num

line = many value
```

then "rinse and repeat", with `getLine` until you EOF.

*Note:* you can do it *without* Parsec using `read` and friends, but this way is more extendable and preferred for more complicated grammars.

Comment: This really isn't useful for solving programming competition problems, which is the only context in which the original question makes sense.

Comment: @Carl It makes sense for the general public not constrained by such silly limitations, and it wasn't explicitely required by the OP. That's *one* of the possible solutions, and I don't think I am wrong in any way for posting it.

Comment: The above can be simplified into `line = many $ spaces >> parseFloat`. And you'd probably want trailing spaces cut off, so perhaps `line = many (spaces >> parseFloat) <* spaces`. Then you'd run it with `main = getLine >>= fmap (parse line "") >>= print`.

In full:
`import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Numbers
import Control.Applicative
line = many (spaces >> parseFloat) <* spaces
main = getLine >>= fmap (parse line "") >>= print`

Answer (score 0):

Using Parsec:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Numbers
import Control.Applicative ((*>), (<*))
line = spaces *> many1 (parseFloat <* spaces)
main = putStrLn "Enter numbers:" >> fmap (parse line "") getLine >>= print
```

Running it:

```
$ ghc parsenums.hs
$ ./parsenums
Enter numbers:
345 23 654 234
[345.0,23.0,654.0,234.0]
```

A more "manual" way to do it would be something like:

```
import Data.Char (isDigit, isSpace)

getInts :: String -> [Int]
getInts s = case span isDigit (dropWhile isSpace s) of
  ("", "") -> []
  ("", s) -> error $ "Invalid input: " ++ s
  (digits, rest) -> (read digits :: Int) : getInts rest
```

Which might be much clearer to see how it works. In fact, here's one that's completely from the ground up:

```
getInts :: String -> [Int]
getInts s = case span isDigit (dropWhile isSpace s) of
  ("", "") -> []
  ("", s) -> error $ "Invalid input: " ++ s
  (digits, rest) -> strToInt digits : getInts rest

isDigit :: Char -> Bool
isDigit c = '0' <= c && c <= '9'

isSpace :: Char -> Bool
isSpace c = c `elem` " \t\n\r"

charToInt :: Char -> Int
charToInt c = fromEnum c - 48

strToInt :: String -> Int
strToInt s = go 0 s where
  go n [] = n
  go n (c:rest) = go (n * 10 + charToInt c) rest
```